# asp.net c# add and remove classes jquery issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I added my JQuery but lose my ability to traverse onto different parts of my navigational websites. Here is a working [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkVEA/12/) of switching classes.

My code navigational code:

```
<form runat="server">
        <div id="new_menu" class="new_menu_header" runat="server">
            <ul>
                <li >
                    <a class="selected" href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="The_Team.aspx">The Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Advisory_Board.aspx">Advisory Board</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</form>
```

The main reason for me placing this form is to show you guys that my href seems to get overwritten onClick(Calls JQuery and ignores Href).

Can someone lend me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for setting up a jsFiddle for this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `return false` from your handler procedure then it will stop the click event. Which means, no navigation (which is the default behavior).

Take out the `return false` and it will try to navigate to the `href` you've set on your `a`.

Comment: ah I see it does that but I have an issue of the original line returning back to its original position "home" whenever I click navigational buttons. Do you have an idea for a fix?

Comment: You're setting `.selected` on Home each page. Make sure each other page sets `.selected` on the right navigation item.

Comment: Alright. Thanks that might be solution I am looking for. I am not sure that this is the right way but I feel that I have to hard-code javascript on each page. Would this be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: It's the easiest way. Otherwise you need to do some sort of helper that compares the link with your current URL and adds the `.selected` automatically. But honestly that might take a lot more work than it saves.